# I want to echo the fullname of the user without him putting it on the form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table that has some values. One of them is the full name of the user. I want to echo the full name from the db that it is saved. I have 2 different tables for the risks and for the users. I thought about doing it with something like `<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['fullname'] ?>` but I don't know where to write that. There is also another page that i pass the values from the form into the db but I don't know if I should echo the full name from there.

```
   <?php require_once('config.php') ?>
<?php 
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) and $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
} 
?>
<?php
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=riskit", "root", "");
$query = "SELECT * FROM risktable ORDER BY riskId";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
?>



<html>
<title>Risk Table</title>
 <head> 
  <?php require_once( ROOT_PATH . '/includes/head_section.php') ?>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <body>

  <div class="container">
  <?php include( ROOT_PATH . '/includes/navbar.php') ?>
   <br />
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">Risk Table</h2><br />
   <h3 align="center">Add Risks</h3>
   <br />
   <form method="post" id="add_details">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Your Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Risk Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="riskName" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Description</label>
     <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Control Enviroment</label>
     <input type="radio" name="controlEnv" class="form-control" required
   <?php if (isset($controlEnv) && $controlEnv=="internal") echo "checked";?>
   value="internal">Internal
  <input type="radio" name="controlEnv" class="form-control" required
  <?php if (isset($controlEnv) && $controlEnv=="external") echo "checked";?>
  value="external">External
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Risk Category</label>
     <input type="text" name="riskCat" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Risk Type</label>
     <input type="radio" name="rtype" class="form-control" required
   <?php if (isset($rtype) && $rtype=="threat") echo "checked";?>
   value="threat">Threat
  <input type="radio" name="rtype" class="form-control" required
  <?php if (isset($rtype) && $rtype=="opportunity") echo "checked";?>
  value="opportunity">Opportunity
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Phase</label>
     <input type="text" name="phase" class="form-control" required />
    </div>  
     <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
    </div>
   </form>
   <br />
   <h3 align="center">View Details</h3>
   <br />
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Risk Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Contol Enviroment</th>
      <th>Risk Category</th>
      <th>Risk Type</th>
      <th>Phase</th>
      <th>Creator</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_data">
    <?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
     echo '
     <tr>
      <td>'.$row["riskName"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["description"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["controlEnv"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["riskCat"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["rtype"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["phase"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["fullname"].'</td>
     </tr>
     ';
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#add_details').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   url:"insertRiskTable.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:$(this).serialize(),
   dataType:"json",
   beforeSend:function(){
    $('#add').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    console.log('before');
   },
   success:function(data){
    $('#add').attr('disabled', false);
    console.log('in success');
    if(data.riskName)
    {
     var html = '<tr>';
     html += '<td>'+data.riskName+'</td>';
     html += '<td>'+data.description+'</td>';
     html += '<td>'+data.controlEnv+'</td>';
     html += '<td>'+data.riskCat+'</td>';
     html += '<td>'+data.rtype+'</td>';
     html += '<td>'+data.phase+'</td>';
     html += '<td>'+data.fullname+'</td></tr>';
     $('#table_data').prepend(html);
     $('#add_details')[0].reset();
    }
   }
  })
 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Look that first two line ? why you do that? alwys session_start() must be write at the top of the page.

Comment: How about `<?php  echo $_SESSION['user']['fullname'];     foreach($result as $row)`

Comment: .. also avoid mixing up all those languages `javascript php html mysql` together in one file

Comment: Remove the spaces in front of this line `<?php require_once('config.php') ?>` it may be causing `session_start()` to not work, as session_start() must be run before ANY OUTPUT to the browser is made and white space counts as output

Comment: It runs fine with how I wrote it. I mean I dont have any issues there. I had session_start() inside config.php before, but i dont know if it will work with the session counter.

Comment: @mplungjan I tried what you proposed, but I just get fullname echoed above my table.  Anyone knows if <td>'.$row.$_SESSION['user']["fullname"].'</td> this is correct or am I just being stupid and messing with my code?

Comment: You were just unclear about WHERE you wanted it - do you mean `html += '<td><?php echo SESSION['user']["fullname"]; ?>< </td></tr>`

Comment: @mplungjan yeah. Is that gonna work?

Comment: Try! Why ask me? I do not have your database

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Oh well. Back to searching.